# Why do we need more executors than number of machines in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

What's the logic behind requesting more executors than machines available in your cluster?

In the ideal situation, we would like to have 1 executor (=1 jvm) at each of our machines, and not few in each machine.
If not, then why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> In the ideal situation, we would like to have 1 executor (=1 jvm) at each of our machines, and not few in each machine.

Not necessarily. Depending on the amount of available memory and JVM implementation separate virtual machines can be much a better option, in particular to:

- Improve memory management with large machines - see for example [Why 35GB Heap is Less Than 32GB – Java JVM Memory Oddities](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/).
- To improve fault tolerance with unstable workloads - if one JVM fails you'll lose work for all corresponding threads, so keeping things smaller can keep things under control.
- To minimize effort required for GC tuning - very large instances can be extremely painful to tune.